Onesignal Live Activity Push To Start Issue
I am working on live activities but couldn't work it properly. I am using react native SDK. I follow documentation step by step. My live activity works if I start from code. But If I try to push to start nothing happens. I can see my notifications delivered properly from the panel.
React Native;
  OneSignal.initialize("*********");
  OneSignal.LiveActivities.setupDefault();

Xcode
import ActivityKit
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import OneSignalLiveActivities

//Your struct name might be different here
struct WidgetExtensionLiveActivity: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: DefaultLiveActivityAttributes.self) { context in
            // Lock screen/banner UI goes here
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Title: ")
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text( "Default Mesasdasdsage")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Text("INT: " + String(context.state.data["intValue"]?.asInt() ?? 0))
                Text("DBL: " + String(context.state.data["doubleValue"]?.asDouble() ?? 0.0))
                Text("BOL: " + String(context.state.data["boolValue"]?.asBool() ?? false))
                Spacer()
            }
            .activitySystemActionForegroundColor(.black)
            .activityBackgroundTint(.white)
        } dynamicIsland: { _ in
            DynamicIsland {
                // Expanded UI goes here.  Compose the expanded UI through
                // various regions, like leading/trailing/center/bottom
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
                    Text("Leading")
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
                    Text("Trailing")
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                    Text("Bottom")
                    // more content
                }
            } compactLeading: {
                Text("L")
            } compactTrailing: {
                Text("T")
            } minimal: {
                Text("Min")
            }
            .widgetURL(URL(string: "http://www.apple.com"))
            .keylineTint(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

Error Message

[DefaultLiveActivityAttributes] Error creating activity: NSCocoaErrorDomain (4865) The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

